# Python short cut to fill list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Java has `Arrays.fill(A,1)`. For a pre-existing List `A`, is there a shortcut for filling the list with `1`? I am writing a function that takes an array and changes the array in some ways. Since arrays are pointers, my function will not return an array. The caller will see the changes after my function returns. The first step in my function is to fill the array with `1s`. Doing

```
def my_work(A):
   A =[1]*len(A) 
   # more work on A
```

does not seem to change `A` when `my_work` is done.

So is my only option

```
for i in range(len(A)):
  A[i]=1
```

or is there a shortcut? Mine looks like a workaround.

Comment: I didn't know I needed to clarify but it seems I do. `my_work` needs to change `A` in place. Therefore, I cannot return A. The caller will simply call `my_work(A)` and after my work returns, A is supposed to have been changed. The caller will not do `A = my_work(A)`. That would not be in-place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to change `A` in place, the `A[:]` syntax should work:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> def my_work(A):
...     A[:] = [1]*len(A) 
...     
>>> A
[1, 2, 3]
>>> my_work(A)
>>> A
[1, 1, 1]
```

And [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) is the relevant section of the tutorial ("assignment to slices").

Comment: Since I had just posted my answer, I deleted mine as your is better.

Answer (score 0):

A is not changing because your not returning it our of `my_work`. Once my_work is complete the A you have in there is not referenced.

```
def my_work(A):
    A =[1]*len(A) 
    return A  #This line is needed

A = my_work(A)
```

Another way to do this is something like this.

```
def reset_list(L, x):
     return [x for i in xrange(len(L))]

A = reset_list(A,1)
```

Comment: how is this different than my answer?

Comment: It's not I was going to ask you the same thing, we crossed.

Comment: I guess I highlight to user1612593 why A is not modififed

Comment: As I say in my post, filling A with 1s is the first step, the function has to do additional work on A. So I can't return immediately as in your case. Also imagine that the person using `my_work` does not want to do `A = my_work(A)`. Since A is an object, my_work should simply change it.